# Radio button array with cloned row

Tags: javascript

I have a form where a row get's clowned if a user clicks "add row". My problem is with the radio buttons, the name of the radio group stays the same and I need to get them unique for each cloned row. This is how I have it at the moment.

```
 <input type="radio" name="chronic_l_duration[]" value="Chronic" />
 <input type="radio" name="chronic_l_duration[]" value="Limited duration" />
```

What I would like is something like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="chronic_l_duration[1]" value="Chronic" />
<input type="radio" name="chronic_l_duration[1]" value="Limited duration" />
```

end when a other row gets added it goes to:

```
 <input type="radio" name="chronic_l_duration[2]" value="Chronic" />
 <input type="radio" name="chronic_l_duration[2]" value="Limited duration" />
```

Javascript I use to clone a row:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var clonedRow = $('.row').clone().html();
    var appendRow = '<tr class = "row">' + clonedRow + '</tr>';  

    $('#btnAddMore').click(function(){

    $('.employmentHistoryForm tr:last').after(appendRow);
    });


    $('.deleteThisRow').live('click',function(){
    var rowLength = $('.row').length;

    if(rowLength > 1){
    deleteRow(this);
    }else{
    $('.employmentHistoryForm tr:last').after(appendRow);
    deleteRow(this);
    }
    });

    function deleteRow(currentNode){
    $(currentNode).parent().parent().remove();
    }
    });
```

So each time the row get's cloned the radio button has a unique value.

Is there maybe a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the appended row with the `$('.employmentHistoryForm tr:last')` and then modify the name of input:

```
$('#btnAddMore').click(function(){
   $('.employmentHistoryForm tr:last').after(appendRow);
   $('.employmentHistoryForm tr:last input[type="radio"]').attr('name', 'desired value');
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for helping me, how would I get a number in block quotes behind the name?